# How to install skins in NetBeans codename one plugin

Tags: codenameone

I'm new to Netbeans. I'm using the codename one plugin. How do I install skins (iphone3s, android, lumia) to preview my app in different phones?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is explained [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/unskin-proxy-support.html). There is also a tool to create new skins covered [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/skin-designer.html).

Just click the `More` button in the `Skins` menu. Make sure your proxy is configured correctly.

Comment: But when I click on 'more' a window appears saying 'please wait' and it just takes forever. My proxy setting is 'use system proxy'. I've also downloaded the skins from github, but I don't know where should I copy the skins.

Comment: Do you see anything in the console during the "please wait"? Is your connection very slow? Make sure you downloaded the proper binary skins and not the HTML files, they need to be skin files and not the properties etc. then use the Add Skin menu item.